'90s movie with a blue monster in a desert underground base
I'm looking for a 90s movie which I saw as a kid; it was kind of sci-fi. 
There was a group of people in the desert and they went to some kind of underground base. One of the guys either turns into a monster or there was a monster loose in this base. But I remember one of the girls in the movie was either asleep or crawling through a vent-like area where this blue monster attacks and rapes her. 
When the others found her there was a sticky cobweb-like substance all over the place. I think they hunted down the blue monster and eventually escaped the underground base and drove through the desert in some kind of buggy-like vehicle.
Can anyone remember the name of this movie?  

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points.  The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

Ok SOME of what you are describing sounds like the film "little monsters" blue monster and the cobweb stuff specifically. Again not a film I've seen or if I did it was many moons ago. See the trailer below and see if it rings any bells.




Thanks but Little Monsters is not the Movie I'm looking for . Altho I might have seen it a long time ago …
